# How to get device width/height in React without calling the window object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Is there a way to access device width or height in React or Next.js without using "window." or "document.". I understand we can get this with the hook useEffect and we don't have this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

but that's an overkill if I just need to access the width once

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const LayoutContainer = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window.innerWidth < 450, window.innerWidth);
    setMobile(window.innerWidth);
    return () => setMobile(window.innerWidth < 450);
  }, [window.innerWidth]); //ReferenceError: window is not defined

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer mobile={mobile} />
    </>
  );
};

export default LayoutContainer;
```

Comment: `window is not defined` is not related to React lifecycle, since window is the global object and it does not care if DOM is mounted or not. You get that error if you are using SSR like Next.js, since on server window object does not exist. That's not overkill by the way, you just need a custom hook that does that and you can call in one line where you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `window.matchMedia` but instead, add an event listener in the `useEffect` and remove the `window` dependency, like this:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [isWide, setIsWide] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
    const onChange = () => setIsWide(!!mql.matches);

    mql.addListener(onChange);
    setIsWide(mql.matches);

    return () => mql.removeListener(onChange);
  }, []);

  return <div>Is Wide: {isWide ? "true" : "false"}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Inspired by https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useMedia.ts

If you are looking to completely remove your `useEffect`, I supposed you could do something like this if you only need to find the width once on mount:

```js
  let isMobile = null;
  
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    isMobile = window.innerWidth < 450;
  }

  console.log(isMobile);
```

Comment: I understand I can use the useeffect hook, I'm working with Next.js and at times window is not defined too

Comment: As far as I know, `window` will always be defined inside the `useEffect` with Next.js

Comment: @ChukwuEmeka As @AliKlein mentioned, `window` will always be defined _inside_ the `useEffect` as it only runs on the client-side. However, in your code you're accessing `window` in the `useEffect`'s dependencies array, where it will be `undefined` during pre-rendering on the server.

Comment: I think it's unnecessary calling useEffect just to get screen size, my question is, Is there a shorter way to do this in react, like since we have window object in Dom, is it possible that we have virtualDom object?

Comment: I edited my answer to offer a solution without `useEffect`. This will only work to get that value on mount. It will not update on resizing.